# Ansible aws_ec2 plugin multiple private ips

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an ec2 machine with 3 enis attached (3 private ips), the eni with ssh access security group is not the main private-ip. i've tried the following dynamic inventory:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-west-1
filters:
  tag:Name: test_ec2
groups:
  tag_testMachine_true: "true == true"
hostnames:
  - network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address
compose:
  ansible_host: private-ip-address
```

this is the output for ansible-inventory command:

```
@all:
  |--@aws_ec2:
  |  |--['10.16.1.31', '10.16.2.15', '10.16.3.11']
```

when running ansible with this inventory, getting the following error:

```
fatal: [['10.16.1.31', '10.16.2.15', '10.16.3.11']]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ['10.16.1.31', '10.16.2.15', '10.16.3.11']: Name does not resolve", "unreachable": true}
```

While I only need the third ip (10.16.3.11), is there a way to choose a specific ip of an ec2?

Comment: If you trust the order in which the hosts are returned for the given group => `hosts: aws_ec2[2]`. If the number of hosts in group might vary but you are sure it is always the last one => `hosts: aws_ec2[-1]`

Comment: thanks! I've tried it and it didnt work, I think because aws_ec2[0] is an array, i've tried accessing using aws_ec2[0][2] also but i guess its not allowed

Comment: I use this daily to target first or last target of database groups so I can guaranty it works (at least from a non-aws inventory...). What is the error you get ? Meanwhile you probably have much better methods to tune your inventory result from the config file (changing how you return the hostname for example, choosing something more meaningfull than the ip...)

Comment: I'm getting the following: ERROR! No hosts matched the subscripted pattern 'aws_ec2[2]'

Comment: and what happens if you use `aws_ec2` ?

Comment: fatal: [['10.16.1.31', '10.16.2.15', '10.16.3.11']]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ['10.16.1.31', '10.16.2.15', '10.16.3.11']: Name does not resolve", "unreachable": true}

Comment: Well the the problem is in your inventory config file. Check documentation for the plugin but `network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address` is not good for a host name.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering more than 2 years later.

**Short answer**

I was able to get the right private IP by setting the `hostnames` of my `aws_ec2.yml` as `private-ip-address` in place of `network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address`.

```yaml
---
# https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/docsite/aws_ec2_guide.html

plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2

[..]

compose:
  ansible_host: private_ip_address

hostnames:
   - private-ip-address # This allows to return the right private IP for me
   - network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address # This was the previous value which returns an array of IPs
```

---

**Long answer**

I had the same problem today when I wanted to limit the play to a specific host which has several private IPs (EKS node).
My inventory returned an array for the hostname which I can't use to limit my play.

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/ec2-dev-v2/aws_ec2.yaml --graph
..
  |--@ec2-dev-v2:
  |  |--@ec2:
  |  |  |--['172.17.26.27', '172.17.26.189']
  |  |  |--['172.17.27.231', '172.17.24.160']
  |  |  |--172.17.2.90
  |  |  |--172.17.0.89
  |  |  |--['172.17.21.177', '172.17.20.193']
  |  |  |--['172.17.29.113', '172.17.30.77', '172.17.30.87']
  |  |  |--['172.17.29.58', '172.17.30.165']
```

Trying to limit the play using the hostname failed like this:

```bash
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/ec2-dev-v2 playbooks/wazuh-agent.yml --limit "['172.17.29.113', '172.17.30.77', '172.17.30.87']"
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: ['172.17.29.113'
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: '172.17.30.77'
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: '172.17.30.87']
ERROR! Specified inventory, host pattern and/or --limit leaves us with no hosts to target
```

I was able to get the right private IP by setting the `hostnames` of my `aws_ec2.yml` as `private-ip-address` in place of `network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address`.

```yaml
---
# https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/docsite/aws_ec2_guide.html

plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2

use_contrib_script_compatible_ec2_tag_keys: true

filters:
  instance-state-name:
    - running

[..]

compose:
  ansible_host: private_ip_address


hostnames:
   - private-ip-address # This allows to return the right private IP for me
   - network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address # This was the previous value which returns an array of IPs
```

Then the dynamic inventory returns only one IP.

```bash
$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/ec2-dev-v2/aws_ec2.yaml --graph
..
  |--@ec2-dev-v2:
  |  |--@ec2:
  |  |  |--172.17.26.27
  |  |  |--172.17.24.160
  |  |  |--172.17.2.90
  |  |  |--172.17.0.89
  |  |  |--172.17.20.193
  |  |  |--172.17.30.87
  |  |  |--172.17.30.165
```

Then I could limit the play as wished.

```bash
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/ec2-dev-v2 playbooks/wazuh-agent.yml --limit 172.17.30.87

PLAY [Install Wazuh Agent on EKS nodes] *************************************
Thursday 13 July 2023  16:51:41 +0200 (0:00:06.190)       0:00:06.190 *******

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************
ok: [172.17.30.87]
Thursday 13 July 2023  16:51:58 +0200 (0:00:16.536)       0:00:22.726 *******
..
```

I hope this can help some people.