# Ansible aws_ec2 plugin set ansible_host: from multiple private ips based on 'description:'

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible-inventory

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231298/ansible-aws-ec2-plugin-multiple-private-ips_), but it doesn't really help me.

### Symptom

Using EC2 Dynamic Inventory, I am unable to configure the `ansible_host:` var to the `private-ip-address:` of a specific interface when there are two interfaces available with `private-ip-address:` on different subnets.

### Reason for question

The two interfaces in use on the hosts are `management` and `server-lan`.  The Ansible Control node can only access hosts via the `management` interface.

**Note: I've simplified the code for reading and changed the host and IP details.**

I have the following very simple example ec2_aws inventory file.

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-west-x
filters:
  tag:Name: ec2-host-01
  instance-state-name: running
keyed_groups:
  # Add hosts to tag_Name_Value groups for each Name/Value tag pair
  - prefix: tag
    key: tags
hostnames:
  - tag:Name
compose:
  ansible_host: private-ip-address
```

My sample host has 2 Network interfaces `management` and `server-lan`, as identified in the `description:`.

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "ec2-host-01": {
                .....
                "network_interfaces": [
                    {...
                         "description": "management",
                         "private_ip_addresses": [
                             {
                                 "primary": true,
                                 "private_dns_name": "ip-10-0-1-1.eu-west-x.compute.internal",
                                 "private_ip_address": "10.0.1.1"
                             }
                         ],
                    },
                    {...
                         "description": "server-lan",
                         "private_ip_addresses": [
                             {
                                 "primary": true,
                                 "private_dns_name": "ip-10-0-20-1.eu-west-x.compute.internal",
                                 "private_ip_address": "10.0.20.1"
                             }
                         ],
                    }
...
}
```

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but both interfaces have `primary: true`.

This is the output I currently get from the `ansible-inventory` command. The ec2 plugin appears to randomly assign the `ansible_host` .  Where as I need to set the `ansible_host`  var to the IP address of the management interface.  Currently, I am unable to specify the private-ip-address of the management interface.

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "ec2-host-01": {
                "ami_launch_index": 0,
                "ansible_host": "10.0.20.1",       ## NB: This should be 10.0.1.1
                "architecture": "x86_64",
                "block_device_mappings": [
....
```

Here is the output of the `ansible-inventory --graph --vars` command:

```
  |  |--ec2-host-01
  |  |  |--{ansible_host = 10.0.20.1}
  ...............
  |  |  |--{network_interfaces = [{'attachment': {'attach_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 13, 45, 38, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'attachment_id': 'eni-attach-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'delete_on_termination': False, 'device_index': 1, 'status': 'attached', 'network_card_index': 0}, 'description': 'server-lan', 'groups': [{'group_name': 'server_group', 'group_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}], 'ipv6_addresses': [], 'mac_address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 'network_interface_id': 'eni-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'owner_id': '123456789123', 'private_dns_name': 'ip-10-0-20-1.eu-west-x.compute.internal', 'private_ip_address': '10.0.20.1', 'private_ip_addresses': [{'primary': True, 'private_dns_name': 'ip-10-0-20-1.eu-west-x.compute.internal', 'private_ip_address': '10.0.20.1'}], 'source_dest_check': True, 'status': 'in-use', 'subnet_id': 'subnet-management-xxxxxx', 'vpc_id': 'vpc-abc123xxxxxxxxxx', 'interface_type': 'interface'}, {'attachment': {'attach_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 13, 45, 38, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'attachment_id': 'eni-attach-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'delete_on_termination': False, 'device_index': 0, 'status': 'attached', 'network_card_index': 0}, 'description': 'management', 'groups': [{'group_name': 'server_group', 'group_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}], 'ipv6_addresses': [], 'mac_address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 'network_interface_id': 'eni-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'owner_id': '123456789123', 'private_dns_name': 'ip-10-0-1-1.eu-west-x.compute.internal', 'private_ip_address': '10.0.1.1', 'private_ip_addresses': [{'primary': True, 'private_dns_name': 'ip-10-0-1-1.eu-west-x.compute.internal', 'private_ip_address': '10.0.1.1'}], 'source_dest_check': True, 'status': 'in-use', 'subnet_id': 'subnet-lan-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'vpc_id': 'vpc-abc123xxxxxxxxxx', 'interface_type': 'interface'}]}
  |  |  |--{private_dns_name = ip-10-0-20-1.eu-west-x.compute.internal}
  |  |  |--{private_dns_name_options = {'hostname_type': 'ip-name', 'enable_resource_name_dns_a_record': False, 'enable_resource_name_dns_aaaa_record': False}}
  |  |  |--{private_ip_address = 10.0.20.1}
  ...............
  |  |  |--{source_dest_check = True}
  |  |  |--{state = {'code': 16, 'name': 'running'}}
  |  |  |--{state_transition_reason = }
  ...............
  |  |  |--{usage_operation = RunInstances}
  |  |  |--{usage_operation_update_time = 2022-07-13 13:45:38+00:00}
```

### Required Result

I need to be able to configure the `aws_ec2.yml` configuration file (possibly via the `compose:` key) to set the `ansible_host:` var as the `private-ip-address` of the `management` interface.

```
compose:
  # I need to set this var to:  10.0.1.1  eg: the management interface IP.
  ansible_host: private-ip-address ???????
```

[β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%ce%b2-%ce%b5%ce%b7%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%84-%ce%b2%ce%b5) has already provided a solution to be able to retrieve the `management` and `server-lan` ip addresses during a playbook run ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988033/get-private-ip-from-multi-home-aws-ec2-dynamic-inventory-host)), but this is different, as this is defining the inventory vars.

Comment: I don't really get the question for the private address part, doesn't this work: `ansible_host: private-ip-address`? If not, what does `ansible-inventory --graph --vars` gives you?

Comment: Note that `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_host }}` and `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].lan_interface }}` are extremely complicated ways to do `{{ ansible_host }}` and `{{ lan_interface }}`

Comment: Hi Benoit,  ```ansible_host: private-ip-address```  gives me the LAN IP which is firewalled, and hence not connecting.  I've not seen any example where you can specify the Interface you need to use from the EC2 metadata.  ```ansible-inventory --graph --vars```, not seen that cmd before, will run it and let you know.

Comment: I've uploaded the sanitised version of the ```ansible-inventory --graph --vars``` output.   I'm guessing you are thinking of how to extract the ```private-ip-address``` based on the ```description``` value from the ```network_interfaces``` dictionary.

Comment: Have updated the post to add some clarity (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
plugin: aws_ec2
cache: yes
regions:
  - eu-central-1
hostnames:
  - tag:Name
filters:
  instance-state-name:
    - running
compose:
  ansible_host: network_interfaces | selectattr('description', 'defined') | selectattr('description', '==', 'management') | map(attribute='private_ip_addresses') | map(attribute='private_ip_address') | join('')
```

Comment: This works a treat thank you Markus.   I just need to see if I can include the option of selecting an interface with a different description.... but I'll get this working first !